# Открытия pro файла в visual studio

Tags: qt, visual-studio

Я пишу програмку в visual studio c++ с установленым дополнениям qt. Мне нужно открыть pro файл qt, чтобы добавить туда несколько строк. На вкладке qt5 есть кнопка open QT Project File (.pro). Когда я ее нажимаю открыватся папка с проектом, где нет никаких .pro файлов.

Как быть?

Может, если это не возможно, то как преобразовать .pro в vsproj?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас должен быть пункт меню "QtX", там "Qt Project Settings".

[image: Imgur]

А чтобы править мануально можно попробовать добавить в проект этот файл вручную.

Comment: я создаю .pro файл с помощью команды Create basic .pro File, добавляю его в проект как существующий елемент. Компилирую проект: .pro файл не участвует в компиляции.

Comment: @luyus
.
http://doc.qt.digia.com/vs-add-in-1.1.7/vs-addin-managing-projects.html
.
Судя по всему, редактировать настройки Qt-проекта можно только через виззард. "Create basic *.pro" нужен для кроссплатформенности и в виндах толку от него нет.